# A couple of questions regarding a short proof of the Jordan Decomposition Theorem.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, signed-measures

> **Theorem 6.21 (Jordan decomposition).**
> If $\nu$ is a signed measure on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{A})$, then there exist unique measures $\nu^+, \nu^- \colon \mathcal{A} \to [0, \infty]$, one of which is finite, such that
> $$
>   \nu = \nu^+ - \nu^- \quad\text{and}\quad \nu^+ \perp \nu^- \,.
> $$
>
> *Proof.*
> Let $X = P \cup N$ where $P$, $N$ are positive, negative sets for $\nu$.
> Then
> $$
>   \nu^+(A) = \nu(A \cap P) \,,
>   \quad
>   \nu^-(A) = -\nu(A \cap N)
> $$
> is the required decomposition.
> The values of $\nu^{\pm}$ are independent of the choice of $P$, $N$ up to a $\nu$-null set, so the decomposition is unique.

---

**Question 1:** why are the values of $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ independent of the decomposition chosen? That is, for another decomposition of $X$ into a disjoint positive $P'$ and negative set $N'$, why do we have
$$
  \nu(A \cap P) = \nu(A \cap P') \,?
$$

My thoughts: we have
\begin{align*}
  \nu(A \cap P)
  &= \nu(A \cap P \cap P') + \nu(A \cap (P \setminus P')) \\
  &\stackrel{?}{=} \nu(A \cap P \cap P') + \nu(A \cap (P' \setminus P))
   \tag{$*$} \\ 
  &= \nu(A \cap P')
\end{align*}
where the sets $P \setminus P'$ and $P' \setminus P$ are $\nu$-null. If we were dealing with a (positive) measure I could use monoticity to show
$$
  \nu(A \cap (P \setminus P')) = 0 = \nu(A \cap (P \setminus P'))
$$
and prove the equality in $(*)$.

**Question 2:** even if $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are independent of the decomposition chosen, how does that show that they are the unique singular measures with the property
$$
  \nu = \nu^+ - \nu^- \,?
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** You may write $A\cap(P-P')=A\cap P\cap N'$, then it's a subset of P with $\nu\ge 0 $;
it's also a subset of N' with $\nu\le 0$; so $\nu(A\cap(P-P'))=0$.

**Q2:** If there is another decomposition: $\nu=\nu_1-\nu_2$, here $\nu_{1, 2}$ are singular measures. Then there exist disjointed $P'', N''$ satisfy $$X=P''\cup N'',\quad \nu_1(N'')=\nu_2(P'')=0.$$
We can prove that $P''$ is a positive set, $N''$ is a negative set, then go back to **Q1**.